# "error: neither -p product specified nor ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT set" when trying to `fastboot flashall -w` on Nexus 7

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, nexus-7

I am trying to flash the latest 6.0.1 build onto my Nexus 7 tab.
I picked MOB30X build from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images#razor)

```
naveen@gandalf:~$ fastboot devices
015d2a4ffd181016    fastboot
```

But, when I do

```
naveen@gandalf:~$ fastboot flashall -w
error: neither -p product specified nor ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT set
```

What is this product about?

Further,
Looking like the build comes with a nice installation file **flash-all.sh**
While running

```
fastboot -w update image-razor-mob30x.zip
```

I'm again hitting this error

> checking product... 
> FAILED

Here's the complete log [file](https://www.writeurl.com/text/cywsk5vsp955bu3mdbtn/sde6c1hoj0551yeqytg9)

```
naveen@gandalf:~/Playground/android/razor-mob30x$ sudo fastboot -w update image-razor-mob30x.zip
[sudo] password for naveen: 
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
archive does not contain 'vendor.img'
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 30550261760
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8192
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label: 
    Blocks: 7458560
    Block groups: 228
    Reserved block group size: 1024
Created filesystem with 11/1867776 inodes and 161260/7458560 blocks
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 464519168
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7088
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1772
    Label: 
    Blocks: 113408
    Block groups: 4
    Reserved block group size: 31
Created filesystem with 11/28352 inodes and 3654/113408 blocks
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 4.23
Baseband Version.....: N/A
Serial Number........: 015d2a4ffd181016
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
FAILED

Device product is 'grouper'.
Update requires 'flo'.

finished. total time: 0.157s
```

Comment: `fastboot flashall` is AFAIR not the correct command to flash a factory ROM. You have to directly execute `flash-all.bat` / `flash-all.sh` without fastboot.

Comment: Just unzipped and went through flash-all.sh. Looking like that's what is needed. Running it now.

Comment: I was not able to see any output for flash-all for almost 30 mins. I aborted the execution and ran the first command. "fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-flo-flo-04.08.img". Now seeing the message "< waiting for device >"

Comment: Finally got past this when I ran with `"sudo"`. Now seeing _"signature mismatch"_ while flashing bootloader. **sha256sum** seems to be fine. This is something else.

Comment: _Signature mismatch_ seems to be OK. The older bootloader should be able to handle the flashing/installation. I'm seeing an error again. `"checking product...
FAILED"` Will attach the complete log to this post.

Comment: The bottom of your log states an issue with devices variant: "Device product is 'grouper'. Update requires 'flo'". You may have downloaded the wrong firmware.

Comment: So... according to the [Driver Binaries](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers), "grouper" is Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi) while "flo" is Nexus 7 **[2013]** (Wi-Fi)..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` in `/etc/environment`.
You may have a folder with `boot.img` and `system.img` etc. in, this is the right folder.

Example:

```
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/path/to/folder/with/images/
```

After that, you can call `sudo fastboot flashall -w`.

It also works for self-builds.

Answer (score 1):

fastboot is trying to play it safe, and make sure you're not flashing from the wrong location. The easy way is just to `export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=./`, and run fastboot (or fastboot script) in the same directory as your firmware images.

Comment: Marking Andrew / Robybyte's answer as it is a little more descriptive for the readers. I understand you were saying the same thing. Got past it! Phewww!